# knex create table and insert data from array

Tags: knex.js, jsx

I have the following code in the migration file:

```
import knex from 'knex'
import filterWordsArray from '../seeds/filter_words'
const tables = ['filter_words'];

export async function up(knex) {
  await knex.schema.createTable('filter_words', (t) => {
    t.uuid('id').primary().defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
    t.string('word');
  }).then(function () {
    return knex("filter_words").insert(
      filterWordsArray
    );
  })

  return Promise.resolve();
};

export async function down(knex) {
  for (let table of tables) {
    await knex.schema.dropTable(table);
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

The file containing `filterWordsArray` has the following:

```
export const filterWordsArray = [
{ 
word: "something"
},
{ 
word: "rather"
},
{ 
word: "filter"
},
{ 
word: "another"
},
. . .
];
```

I run `knex migrate:latest` , no errors.

```
$> knex migrate:latest
Using environment: development
Batch 3 run: 1 migrations
.../migrations/23460417191457_add_filter_words.js
$>
```

But when I look at the database, the table is created but no data has been inserted.

So this is a Postgresql database; if I were to insert the data manually I would go:

```
mydb=# insert into filter_words(word) values ('something');
mydb=# select * from filter_words;
                  id                  |   word
--------------------------------------+-----------
 2ab8f5d0-ce20-41c2-a0e9-49cbe1b4bd3b | something
(1 row)
```

What am I missing here please ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out one way to make it work, not sure if it's the only / best one. Changed the import to :

```
import {filterWordsArray} from '../seeds/filter_words'
```